# Unable to override model save()

Tags: django, django-models

Trying to execute some code when the Profile model gets updated but it appears the save method never gets called as the print statement never shows.

```
Profile.objects.filter(user__id=1).update(field_a='test')
```

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Test")
        super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the save method is not called. See [the docs on `update()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#update):

> Finally, realize that `update()` does an update at the SQL level and, thus, does not call any `save()` methods on your models, nor does it emit the `pre_save` or `post_save` signals (which are a consequence of calling `Model.save()`). If you want to update a bunch of records for a model that has a custom `save()` method, loop over them and call `save()`, like this:
>
> ```
> for e in Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__year=2010):
>     e.comments_on = False
>     e.save()
> ```